# Html class tag not detected within Jquery when datatables populated using a json dict

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables

I have a datatable, with one of the columns with a "PRINT" option. The table visually looks like this:

[image]

The HTML for the rows are loaded from a JSON dict generated from django views.

The HTML for the column 3 is like this:

```
<button class="classname_for_js">
    PRINT
</button>
```

I have a javascript file: `print.js`:

```
jQuery(".classname_for_js").on('click', printData);
```

printData() is a function that calls a printing API for printing.

For debugging I am trying to console:

```
jQuery(".classname_for_js").on('click', function(){
     console.log("Printing.....");
});
```

However, I get nothing on the console.

I have another datatable whose data is not populated from a json dict, for which the Print button works correctly.

Is there anything I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your click handler like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.classname_for_js', function () {
    console.log("Printing.....");
});
```

You can replace `document` with any parent element that exists on dom already

> **Note:** Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected
>   elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the
>   call to .on().

Comment: I think you need to tell that you suggest the usage of a ***delegated handler***, which will work on HTML injected dynamically.  Besides that I believe your answer is correct.

Comment: @Deesha, you should use `'body'` or even better your `'#tableId'` or the `#container` your table is part of; `document` is the worst you can use, since **every** click in the entire DOM scope will be compared with the second selector each and every time. This is a huge overhead, and it will slow down the response time since your click bubbles up from the outer most element imaginable.  Personally I think the advise of using `$(document).on(` is really, really bad. Imagine you have 10 delegated handlers on 200 elements, all referring to the document root. A huge overhead.

Comment: I gave the table an id, but that seemed to not work. @davidkonrad